# Drawing on NetBeans GUI-builder designed panels?

Tags: java, netbeans

I transferred a GUI I made with Netbeans GUI-builder to Eclipse.  I am wondering if I this scary-looking message the GUI-builder puts in the code is still relevant:

```
  * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
private void initComponents() {
```

I believe that the "Form Editor" can't "regenerate" the content since the code is no longer in NetBeans but I am not completely sure that the "Form Editor" isn't something that is brought along with the code (like in an import?).

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is no longer relevant as you are now within a new ide Eclipse and no longer Netbeans, the editor fold... is used within netbeans to help the ide detect regions to fold within the code. However note that as you can tamper with comments and the code fold xml, its important you avoid tampering with the code generated by netbeans (unless you are sure of what you are doing) to avoid unpredictable behavior in the GUI. The file is now seen as a regular java file within eclipse.

Hope this helps, Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That comment is no longer relevant because you're no longer using that file with the Form Editor plugin; now it's just like any other Java file you've got.

The Form Editor isn't brought along with the code, but instead it generates Java code for you based on the GUI that you create.

The plugin likely generates an instance initialization block like the following:

```
{
    initComponents();
}
```

It uses an instance initialization block because that means that it will be executed regardless of which constructor is called, thus guaranteeing that `initComponents()` will happen.
The other part of that comment refers to the fact that the plugin specifically generates the `initComponents()` method based on external data, likely an XML file. If you modify that method by hand, it will be deleted and regenerated on the next compile.